# Transforming Observable’s output from Object to Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, object, rxjs

I have a Cloud Firestore document that is supposed to be an array of objects. It looks like this

```
docname: {
  0: {...}
  1: {...}
  2: {...}
```

This is expected, because I populated that document like this

```
myDocRef.set( {...user.myArray});
```

The problem I have is when I go to retrieve the data from the document.
I currently do it like this

```
getUserItems(uid) {
  return this._db.doc<MyObj>(`users/${uid}/mysubcollection/items`).valueChanges(); 
}
```

That returns an object of objects and I need it to be an array of objects so that I can use `forEach()` on it.

I tried using the `map()` operator but its giving me some results I am not understanding.

So, my goal is to convert that object of objects to an array of objects and I tried this

```
items$.pipe(
      tap(item => console.log('before map', item )),
      map(item => [item]),
      tap(item => console.log('after map', item ))
    )
    .subscribe(...);
```

This does kind of work since it converts the object of objects to an array of objects but of course it puts all objects into the first dim of a two dim array to it looks like this

```
Array [Object(9)]
```

What can I do here to convert an object of objects to an array of objects so that my end result is like this

```
Array(9) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…} ]
```

So going from this

```
Object(9) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…} ]
```

to this

```
Array(9) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…} ]
```

Comment: Why don't you create an empty array first and push each item in the array inside the "pipe" method?

Answer (score 1):

If the order of the items in the array does not matter, you can just use `Object.values`:

```js
const objectOfObjects = {
  0: { name: "Zero" },
  1: { name: "One" },
  2: { name: "Two" },
  3: { name: "Three" }
};
const unorderedArray = Object.values(objectOfObjects);
console.log(unorderedArray);
```

If they do matter, get both the key and the value first using `Object.entries`, then sort them in ascending order, and `map` out the values:

```js
const objectOfObjects = {
  0: { name: "Zero" },
  1: { name: "One" },
  2: { name: "Two" },
  3: { name: "Three" }
};
const orderedArray = Object.entries(objectOfObjects).sort(([a], [b]) => a - b).map(([, obj ]) => obj);
console.log(orderedArray);
```